# How to save my arrays to local storage with specific number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have problem with my arrays. I have few arrays and I need save them with specific number to local storage.

I want to take all items, turn this items to arrays and save them to local storage with specific number.
First is 0 then 1 and so on.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you

JS

```
let length = document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
    for(number = 0; number < length; number++){
      console.log(number);
    }
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(item => {
      let product = [
        {
          name: item.children[0].children[1].innerHTML,
          price: item.children[1].children[0].innerHTML,
          value: item.children[0].children[0].value
        }
      ]
      localStorage.setItem(`product${number}`, JSON.stringify(product));
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="left"><input type="number" name="pieces" value="1" class="piece"> <p>Kelímek Jelen Extra</p></div><div class="right"><h3 class="price-i">699</h3><h3>Kč</h3> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="left"><input type="number" name="pieces" value="1" class="piece"> <p>Kelímek Jelen Extra</p></div><div class="right"><h3 class="price-i">699</h3><h3>Kč</h3> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="left"><input type="number" name="pieces" value="1" class="piece"> <p>Kelímek Jelen Extra</p></div><div class="right"><h3 class="price-i">699</h3><h3>Kč</h3> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can acheive desired result by using index in foreach loop
foreach loop return index of current item which you can use to store by index in localstorage

Solution :

```
let length = document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((item,index) => {
      let product = [
        {
          name: item.children[0].children[1].innerHTML,
          price: item.children[1].children[0].innerHTML,
          value: item.children[0].children[0].value
        }
      ]

      localStorage.setItem(`product${index}`, JSON.stringify(product));
    });
```

Result :

[image]